# JSON Array is null when passed to an ActionResult controller

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

im passing my json array from view to controller which works fine if i do it this way:

```
    public ActionResult GetValue(string[] name)
    {
        return Json(name);
    }
```

However, when I try to pass it to an ActionResult method, its always returning null?

```
// POST
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "Student")]
public ActionResult Submit(string[] name) // name is null
{

return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

This is my view:

```
var tag = [["Incident Type 1"],["Incident Type 2"]]

$('#SubmitBtn').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "@Url.Action("Submit", "Controller")",
            traditional: true,
            data: { name: tag },
            success: function (msg) { alert(msg) } //alert Incident Type 1, Incident Type 2 when passed to GetValue action
        });
});
```

Comment: What is the value of `tag`? And why are you passing string instead of a collection of objects so its bound correctly to your model?

Comment: And your `Submit` action would  never be executed because of the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` - an error would be thrown (so you are not showing us the correct code)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I edited my post. What do you mean by never executed? Its executing, my only problem is that the when im passing my array to this action the value passed is null. Other codes inside that action method is executed.

Comment: I have a `@Html.AntiForgeryToken() ` in my form if that's what you mean?

Comment: That is not possible - you have not included the token in the request so I can only assume you are making a normal submit as well (`$('#SubmitBtn')` appears to be a submit button ans you have not cancelled it, so that would explain it - you ajax call will be throwing a `500 Internal Server Error`)

Comment: And you can simply test that by changing it to `$('#SubmitBtn').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ... rest of your code });` and you ill see that the method will not be hit, and the error in the browser console

Comment: Note also your `var tag = [{"Incident Type 1"},{"Incident Type 2"}]` makes no sense and its invalid json. Perhaps you meant `[["Incident Type 1"],["Incident Type 2"]]`? but even that makes little sense - you could just use `["Incident Type 1", "Incident Type 2"]` and bind to `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: instead of accepting a string as your parameter and going to the trouble of stringifying it, why not just accept a concrete object and send the JSON directly, unstringified?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I see you're right. So how do I get around the `500 internal server error`?

Comment: You need to pass the token (or remove the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` from the method). But what you are doing suggests a major design problem and you are certainly going about this the wrong way (but you have not shown the code necessary to understand how/why you are passing those values)

Comment: Thank you for your help @StephenMuecke. I passed the token and its working now.

Comment: Will have a look at the fiddle later, but you should be generating `var tags = ["Incident Type 1", "Incident Type 2"];` and then your method will be `IEnumerable<string> tags` so that its automatically bound (but you will need the `traditional: true` ajax option